# How to make all buttons to be of the same height (and keep their weigths)?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, height

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button 
        android:text="BTN1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button 
        android:text="BTN2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
    <Button 
        android:text="BTN3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button 
        android:text="BTN4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button 
        android:text="BTN5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Using `android:layout_height="match_parent"` just stretches the buttons to the whole screen height. I want button 2 to be twice as wide as the other buttons.

Comment: reduce the text size android:textSize="10dp". reduce the text size for all buttons

Comment: @Raghunandan that's not an acceptable solution. I want to keep everything as it is, text size, color, weights, order of the buttons, just button 2, in this case, I want it to match the height of their fellow buttons on the same row

Comment: then it don't think its possible. well i am curious and look forward to a better solution

Comment: yes but the text in the button is not in the same line. does not look good. any i will look at the solution., if you want it in the same line reduce the text size

Comment: @Raghunandan That's the whole point of this question, I don't want the text to be on the same line. I want the height of the buttons to be the same, no matter how many lines of text they display.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This will do:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BTN1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="BTN2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BTN3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BTN4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BTN5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Make the parent layout height `wrap_content` and the 2nd button's height `match_parent`

[image]

Comment: That's almost solution. The reason being that here I put an example with button text "BTNx". In real life the buttons' texts are not known in advance. I tried your solution of setting the parent LinearLayout height to `wrap_content`, but all the buttons (instead of just  "BTN2") heights set to `match_parent` and it works fine, and that's the complete solution for me. thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work if the text of the buttons is three line.Why?

Comment: Hi! Now it is 2022 and the ConstraintLayout is available. Same problem there and it does not support the "gravity" property... Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BTN1as s dh asgdjhsg djahgsd  gsadhasdhg sa" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BTN2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BTN3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BTN4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BTN5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You changed the weight of button 2. I want to be able to play with widths weights.

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it right. the 2nd button is already double the width of the rest of the buttons.

The problem you are left with is the height. The difference in height is because the text inside the buttons are too huge for such small buttons. Just reduce the text size and that should do the magic.

Comment: Even filling vertical space and making the 2nd button "match parent" as suggested by @Archie.bpgc does the wonder

Answer (score -1):

Need to change the LinearLayout height to wrap_content, then change all the heights to match_parent.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="BTN1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="BTN2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="BTN3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:text="BTN4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:text="BTN5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just tested it, it produces the same result.

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to not know what you are talking about. If you read the question you'll see that I did try to `match_parent` and it does not work. Would be nice if you try your suggestion before posting, unless you are completely sure of the solution and can put also some words of explanation why it solves what it solves.

Comment: I tried the updated solution on a device before posting. The match_parent will work if you change the LinearLayout's layout_height to wrap_content.

Comment: Now you are correct, but you forgot to change it in your code. That's the accepted soution, by Archie.bpgc